# Reducer not getting called even after action is dispatched

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk

My use case is that I want to clear some data from my state. For clearing the state, I don't need any api calls hence, I have not written any saga for it.

Action.js

```
export const remove = (payload: string) => {
  console.log('in here', payload)

  return {
    type: types.REMOVE,
     payload
  }
}
```

Reducer.js

```
const selectReducer = (
  state: any = initialState2,
  action: any
) => {
  console.log('selectWorkspacesReducer')
  const { type, payload, error } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case types.REMOVE: {
      console.log('initialState2', initialState2);
      console.log('action', action);
      return {
        ...state,
        ...initialState2,
        p: 1
      }

    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Component

```
   const TreeView = (props: {remove: Function }) => {
const {remove} = props;
      const handleClick = (payload: string) => {
          console.log('payload -> ', payload)
          remove(payload);
        }
      };
    return (
        <div className="tree-view">
          <div className="column" onClick={() => handleClick('test')}>Submit</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
export const mapDispatchToProps = {
  remove
}


export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(TreeView);
```

All the other reducer and actions written in these files work. In case of remove, I am getting the log written in action.js but not in reducer.

Comment: dispatch({
    type: types.REMOVE,
    payload
})

Comment: You seem to be doing it right, can you create a small codesandbox for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to invoke `remove` function, you need to pass action as an argument to dispatch function.

```
dispatch(remove(payload));
```

Answer (score 0):

hi my friend it works :)

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
         remove: (payload)=> dispatch(remove(payload))
      }
}
```

please read this api :)
[https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object--dispatch-ownprops--object][1]

(if you have any questions, ask?)
[1]: https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object--dispatch-ownprops--object